# Vector tile map packages only in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-pro, vector-tiles

I recently came across the .vtpk packages and I want to ask whether the CreateVectorTilePackage_management is available only in ArcGIS Pro or we can access it from ArcMAP 10.4.1. (or directly from arcpy)?

I tried in my Desktop environment and it looks like it is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GeoNet thread on [What are Vector Tiles, and how to use them](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/173243), dated 3 Nov 2016, where an Esri staff member says:

> I can confirm that Vector tiles can only be published from ArcGIS Pro
>   for now. Because its ArcGIS Pro, you can only publish vector tiles to
>   ArcGIS Online or Portal for ArcGIS 10.4, which is federated with
>   ArcGIS Server and has an ArcGIS Data Store.

You should be able to access it from the ArcPy which is installed with ArcGIS Pro but not that which is installed with the ArcGIS 10.x for Desktop architecture.